# \Chapter heading style

Tags: chapters, titlesec, fancybox

Yesterday , I saw a post about a chapter heading style which I liked. And I Was wondering if you could help me achieve the same model (although there are certain differences in the one I want). Thank you in advance.

[image: chapter heading book]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{libertine}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \makeatletter
 \def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter\hspace{1em}#1}%
 \else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
 \fi
\markboth{}{}%
\reset@font
\parindent \z@ 
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\hbox{%
 \vbox{%
  \hsize=7mm%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
    \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\chaptername}\\
    \makebox[7mm]{\cellcolor{black}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thechapter\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \makebox(0,0){\put(-10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}
  }%
\kern-2pt
\vbox to 0pt{%
   \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.1cm}@{}}\hline
      & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
   }%
  \cleardoublepage
%  \vskip 100\p@
}
       \makeatother

   \begin{document}
   \chapter{Books in \LaTeX}


text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

      \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptername~\thechapter\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
\markboth{}{}%
\reset@font
\parindent \z@ 
\vspace*{10\p@}%
    \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
            \hsize=7mm%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
                \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\chaptername}\\
                \makebox[7mm]{\cellcolor{black}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thechapter\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
            \end{tabular}%
            \makebox(0,0){\put(-10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}
        }%
        \kern-2pt
        \vbox to 0pt{%
            \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.1cm}@{}}\hline
            & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
    }%
    \vskip 100\p@
} \makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Books in \LaTeX}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. 

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it gives me 2 errors undefined control sequence argument\cellcolor black huge color white bfseries......and a warning file book has changed

Comment: Perhaps its because  the TOc i defined \newlenght\mylength \renewommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~} \renewcommand\cftchaaftersnum{-}

Comment: In the toc i have 0. Revue of literature 1....... i don't want that. I need to have chapter 1. Revue of literature. Chapter 2......

Comment: Even the shape and the font of my all document had change

Comment: Do you get the errors with my example or with your code?

Comment: With yours. It changed everything in my document especially my toc and the font size of text

Comment: I want in my toc to begin with 1 not 0 and to begin with chapter 1. Not numbers.

Comment: see edited answer ...

Comment: Thank you but its the same error actually i tried to use the package colortbl for the error undefined sequence cellcolor it works BUT i don't konw why the font and size of my body text changed??? Now its smaller and in bold ??? Do you think that the code messes with the text body too and thanks for everything

Comment: Is there another solution with the use of package titlesc

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` ?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work so i tried the package colortbl and it works

Comment: Even my header are gone lol

Comment: with the optional argument `[table]` the package `xcolor` loads by default `colortbl`